# How to make row numbering with ordering, partitioning and grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to make row numbering with ordering, partitioning and grouping. Ordering by `IdDocument, DateChange`, partitioning by `IdDocument` and grouping by `IdRole`. The problem is in grouping especially. As it could be seen from the example (`NumberingExpected`) `DENSE_RANK()` must be the best function for this purpose but it makes repetition of numbering only when the values which are used to order are the same. In my case values used for ordering (`IdDocument, DateChange`) are always different and repetition of numbering must be done by `IdRole`.

Sure it could be solved by the usage of cursor very easy. But is there any way to make it with numbering/ranking functions?

Test data:

```
declare @LogTest as table (
    Id INT
    ,IdRole INT
    ,DateChange DATETIME
    ,IdDocument INT
    ,NumberingExpected INT
)
insert into @LogTest
select 1 as Id, 7 as IdRole, GETDATE() as DateChange, 13 as IdDocument, 1 as NumberingExpected
union 
select 2, 3, DATEADD(HH, 1, GETDATE()), 13, 2
union 
select 3, 3, DATEADD(HH, 2, GETDATE()), 13, 2
union 
select 4, 3, DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()), 13, 2
union 
select 5, 5, DATEADD(HH, 4, GETDATE()), 13, 3
union 
select 7, 3, DATEADD(HH, 6, GETDATE()), 13, 4
union 
select 6, 3, DATEADD(HH, 5, GETDATE()), 27, 1
union 
select 8, 3, DATEADD(HH, 7, GETDATE()), 27, 1
union 
select 9, 5, DATEADD(HH, 8, GETDATE()), 27, 2
union 
select 10, 3, DATEADD(HH, 9, GETDATE()), 27, 3


select * from @LogTest order by IdDocument, DateChange;
```

Explanation in terms of functional programming:

1. Order data by IdDocument, DateChange
2. Set first row number as i=1 go to next row
3. If IdDocument has changed 
   { i=1; }
   else {
       If IdRow has changed { i++; } 
   }
4. set row number as i;
5. go to the next row;
6. IF EOF { exit; } else { go to step 3; }

Comment: What is your decired output?

Comment: @Arion That is the desired output, when the input is the projection of the output on all columns but NumberingExpected.

Comment: @Arion, disired output is NumberingExpected in test query

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko can not get the logic of NumberingExpected. You have it = 1 and IdRole is 3,3 and 7.

Comment: How would you `ORDER BY IdDocument` and `PARTITION BY IdDocument` at the same time? Need clarification here.

Comment: Shouldn't row 3 end in 1?

Comment: @qxg, it is also ordered by DateChange

Comment: @philipxy, no. From row 2 to 4 the number should be 2 cause it's the same  IdRole

Comment: If I've understood your requirements correctly then I don't think you can achieve this using a built-in ranking function. You effectively want to partition by a consecutive *sequence* of DateChange values, rather than discreet DateChange values.

Comment: @RhysJones, want to partition by IdDocument (Numbering starts from 1 again) and to group by IdRole (repetition of numbering, e.g. rows 2-4, 7-8).
2008 R2 version

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko once again. Could you explain why NumberExpected = 1 and IdRole IN (3,7) and IdDocument in (13,27). What is the logic of partitioning?

Comment: I still think an expected output based on the sample data you provided would be the easiest way for all of us to understand exactly what kind of data you are trying to get and that will most likely help you get a correct answer.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, as you can see expected output is provided in test data query, please, check NumberingExpected column.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu See my first comment.

Comment: You are not explaining what NumberingExpected is. Please be clearer. Eg give us a process that generates its values.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks for an idea! I'll give it in terms of functional programming

Comment: Re algorithm: 1. Not quite "functional programming". 2. You don't mention ExpectedNumbering!

Comment: @philipxy, I'm agree about 1st clause. About 2nd, I use phrase "set row number as ..."

Comment: I can *see* that you "set row number as". Your comment doesn't add anything to that. I can *guess* that "set row number as" means "set row's ExpectedNumbering to". I also have to guess what "set ... as i=1" means": "set i to 1; set ... to i". Please just write things clearly. Your shortcuts in text and pseudocode make you hard to understand.

Comment: @philipxy, did my best to give you the idea, and at least Rhys Jones and Vladimir Baranov did understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2012 you could use `LAG`/`LEAD`, but in 2008 it is not available, so we'll emulate it. Performance could be poor, you should check with your actual data.

This is the final query:

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        Main.IdRole
        ,Main.IdDocument
        ,Main.DateChange
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Main.IdDocument ORDER BY Main.DateChange) AS rn
    FROM
        @LogTest AS Main
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP (1) T.IdRole
            FROM @LogTest AS T
            WHERE
                T.IdDocument = Main.IdDocument
                AND T.DateChange < Main.DateChange
            ORDER BY T.DateChange DESC
        ) AS Prev
    WHERE Main.IdRole <> Prev.IdRole OR Prev.IdRole IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM
    @LogTest AS LT
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) CTE_rn.rn
        FROM CTE_rn
        WHERE
            CTE_rn.IdDocument = LT.IdDocument
            AND CTE_rn.IdRole = LT.IdRole
            AND CTE_rn.DateChange <= LT.DateChange
        ORDER BY CTE_rn.DateChange DESC
    ) CA_rn
ORDER BY IdDocument, DateChange;
```

Final Result set:

```
Id    IdRole    DateChange                 IdDocument    NumberingExpected    rn
1     7         2015-01-26 20:00:41.210    13            1                    1
2     3         2015-01-26 21:00:41.210    13            2                    2
3     3         2015-01-26 22:00:41.210    13            2                    2
4     3         2015-01-26 23:00:41.210    13            2                    2
5     5         2015-01-27 00:00:41.210    13            3                    3
7     3         2015-01-27 02:00:41.210    13            4                    4
6     3         2015-01-27 01:00:41.210    27            1                    1
8     3         2015-01-27 03:00:41.210    27            1                    1
9     5         2015-01-27 04:00:41.210    27            2                    2
10    3         2015-01-27 05:00:41.210    27            3                    3
```

### How it works

1) We need the value of IdRole from the previous row when the table is ordered by IdDocument and DateChange. To get it we use `OUTER APPLY` (because `LAG` is not available):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @LogTest AS Main
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) T.IdRole
        FROM @LogTest AS T
        WHERE
            T.IdDocument = Main.IdDocument
            AND T.DateChange < Main.DateChange
        ORDER BY T.DateChange DESC
    ) AS Prev
ORDER BY Main.IdDocument, Main.DateChange;
```

This is result set of this first step:

```
Id    IdRole    DateChange                 IdDocument    NumberingExpected    IdRole
1     7         2015-01-26 20:50:32.560    13            1                    NULL
2     3         2015-01-26 21:50:32.560    13            2                    7
3     3         2015-01-26 22:50:32.560    13            2                    3
4     3         2015-01-26 23:50:32.560    13            2                    3
5     5         2015-01-27 00:50:32.560    13            3                    3
7     3         2015-01-27 02:50:32.560    13            4                    5
6     3         2015-01-27 01:50:32.560    27            1                    NULL
8     3         2015-01-27 03:50:32.560    27            1                    3
9     5         2015-01-27 04:50:32.560    27            2                    3
10    3         2015-01-27 05:50:32.560    27            3                    5
```

2) We want to remove rows with repeating IdRole, so we add a `WHERE` and number the rows. You can see that row numbers follow the expected result:

```
SELECT
    Main.IdRole
    ,Main.IdDocument
    ,Main.DateChange
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Main.IdDocument ORDER BY Main.DateChange) AS rn
FROM
    @LogTest AS Main
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) T.IdRole
        FROM @LogTest AS T
        WHERE
            T.IdDocument = Main.IdDocument
            AND T.DateChange < Main.DateChange
        ORDER BY T.DateChange DESC
    ) AS Prev
WHERE Main.IdRole <> Prev.IdRole OR Prev.IdRole IS NULL
;
```

This is result set of this step (it becomes the CTE):

```
IdRole    IdDocument    DateChange                 rn
7         13            2015-01-26 20:13:26.247    1
3         13            2015-01-26 21:13:26.247    2
5         13            2015-01-27 00:13:26.247    3
3         13            2015-01-27 02:13:26.247    4
3         27            2015-01-27 01:13:26.247    1
5         27            2015-01-27 04:13:26.247    2
3         27            2015-01-27 05:13:26.247    3
```

3) Finally, we need to get the correct row number from CTE for each row of the original table. I use `CROSS APPLY` to get one row from CTE for each row of the original table.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be pretty but it does create the required output.

```
; with cte as (
    select l.Id,l.IdRole,l.IdDocument,l.NumberingExpected,l.DateChange,
    (select min(x.DateChange) from @LogTest x where x.IdDocument = l.IdDocument and x.IdRole = l.IdRole and x.id<=l.id and 
        x.id > (select max(y.id) from @LogTest y where y.IdDocument = l.IdDocument and y.IdRole <> l.IdRole and y.id <=l.Id)) as DateChange2
    from @LogTest l
)
select c.Id,c.IdRole,c.DateChange,c.IdDocument,c.NumberingExpected,dense_rank() over (partition by c.IdDocument order by c.DateChange2) as rn
from cte c order by c.IdDocument, c.DateChange;
```

If I had some more time I think the x.id predicate in the CTE could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RankByIdDocumentAndDataChanged AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        CASE 
             IdRole - LAG(IdRole) OVER (PARTITION BY IdDocument ORDER BY DateChange) 
             WHEN 0 THEN 0 
             ELSE 1 
        END AS DIFF
    FROM @LogTest
)
select *, SUM(DIFF) OVER (PARTITION BY IdDocument ORDER BY DateChange)
from RankByIdDocumentAndDataChanged 
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: LAG is not available in SQL Server 2008 R2.